# Getting a clear view about media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hello there guys i would like to ask some questions about the media queries.

I have being working on a site who already have some responsivess on it.
And i'm forced to write the code on a clild theme and not on the original files so when i try to put inside some new media query it wont work.

Where the problem is

The site defaut media queries are

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 3000px)
#logo {
text-align: center;
padding-right: 120px !important;
float: none !important;
}
```

The target is the logo and i want to write something like this to change it on both landspace and portait.

```
@media screen only (max-width:480px){
#logo{
  margin-left:-23%!important;
}
}

@media screen only (max-width:320px){
#logo{
  margin-left:-39%!important;
}
}
```

When i try that with min-width and not max-width of course it will work but it will mess the rest.

The thought about max-width i have is 
`max-width:320px` -> when the screen resolution under 320 use the code when it is not use the code of the `480px`.

It is wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link?

Comment: https://chris-turner-zg99.squarespace.com/chris-turner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  #logo {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }

  #header {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

And you won't need any media queries for 320px (so you should remove the media queries for 320px)

Comment: that is a mistake i did now when i was write it! still it dosen't work!